# How to echo a word twice and other word one time inside loop

Tags: php, for-loop, data-structures

Hi guys I tried to echo this using php

> even  odd odd even odd odd

and so on .
My code :

```
For( $i = 0 ; $i <=11; $i++    ){

  If( $i % 2 == 0 ) { 
       echo " even " ;
    } 
    If( $i % 2 != 0 ) { 
       echo " odd " ;
        $i = $i+1 ;
    }
}
```

And sure the result is :

> even  odd  odd odd ood

and so on .

I wanted to repeat ( even ) one time and ( odd ) twice  and so on ..
Can someone help me in that ? Thanks

Comment: Why should odd be printed twice? I dont get it... https://3v4l.org/LnrHS

Comment: Why are you incrementing `$i` both in the head of the loop and the body of the loop?

Comment: … _and so on_ until when? What shall be the complete output?

Comment: Nothing much just handle frontend classes ... the issue is ( I have some posts in db and looping through them , first one will take a full width class and second and third one each will take  the half width and so on ... ) hope that helped to understand what's the problem ... thanks for your time...

Answer (score 2):

You can use`%` operator.

Where any counter that is exactly divisible by `3` is even, other case is `odd`.

Answer:

```
for ($i=0 ; $i<=11 ; ++$i) {
 if ($i%3==0) {
  echo "Even";
 }
 else {
  echo "Odd";
 }
}
```

Hand Run:

```
$i - $i%3 - Output
--------------------
0 - 0 - Even 
1 - 1 - Odd 
2 - 2 - Odd 
3 - 0 - Even 
4 - 1 - Odd 
5 - 2 - Odd 
6 - 0 - Even 
7 - 1 - Odd 
8 - 2 - Odd 
9 - 0 - Even 
10 - 1 - Odd 
11 - 2 - Odd
```

**EDIT:** Using ternary operator, you can even reduce the lines of code.

**Reduced Code:**

```
for ($i=0 ; $i<=11 ; ++$i) {
 echo ($i%3==0) ? 'Even' : 'Odd';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could simply use `modulo 3` instead of `2` with a `if`-`else` statement

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++) {
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo 'even ';
    } else {
        echo 'odd ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro for help ... but I don't understand the idea behind using % 3 instead of 2 ... could you give me resources for that issue ... Thanks again

Comment: The modulo operation returns you the remainder of the division. If you divide `5/3` the result is `1` with the remainder `2`, so `5%3` would return `2`. In your case, you have two cases - numbers, which have a remainder of zero and the others. Doing this, every third loop iteration could return an other value. If you need every 4. - simply use modulo 4

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want the desired behaviour of using % 3 as suggested by the others (even though it gets you the result you want) but i'm not sure you'd get the same 'count'. So I'm just going to simply say, why don't you just write 'odd' in your echo statement twice?

```
for( $i = 0 ; $i <=11; $i++    ){

  if( $i % 2 == 0 ) { 
       echo " even " ;
   }else {
       echo " odd odd ";
} 

}
```

If you could help us understand why you want to print odd out twice on the odd numbers that would help? Or whether it doesn't actually matter if `i` is even or odd itself but just the output you're after (as suggested by using % 3).

Comment: I just wanted to handle some classes in frontend by looping through the posts I have in  db and give first one a full witdth class and second and third one give each the half width and so on .. thanks